# Insert to the database error java

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans

i got this error :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Xavega"   at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)  at
>   inspection.management.system.RegistrationForm.InsertRecord(RegistrationForm.java:352)
>     at
>   inspection.management.system.RegistrationForm.button1ActionPerformed(RegistrationForm.java:256)
>     at
>   inspection.management.system.RegistrationForm.access$000(RegistrationForm.java:12)
>     at
>   inspection.management.system.RegistrationForm$1.actionPerformed(RegistrationForm.java:109)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

while trying to inserting JPasswordField text to the database

Here is my code:

```
String _passwordField1 = passwordField1.getText();
int _password = Integer.parseInt(_passwordField1);

try
        {
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);

            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Database";

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            String command = "insert into Member (Password) values (?)";

            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(command);

            statement.setInt(2, _password);

            statement.executeUpdate(command);
        }

catch (Exception e) 
        {
             System.err.println(e.getMessage());

            _sound.PlaySound(2);

            _infoBox.ShowMessageBox(e.getMessage(), "Error", 2);

            _reminder = new Reminder(1);

            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Program will be closed due to error", "Error", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);

            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int _password = Integer.parseInt(_passwordField1);
```

The exception is very clear.

You cannot a string called "`Xavega`" to an `integer`.

Get rid off that line. Because there is no need to convert a password into `integer`.

Insert password as a String in database.

```
  updateTotal.setString(1, _passwordField1);
```

And I'm not sure why you wrote `2` instead of `1`. You should write `1`, because it is first parameter.

Comment: what happen if user enter the password "X345ga"? i mean, what happen if user enter the password mix with string and number value? how do i solve this problem if like that sir? Do i have to tell user to enter a number only or text only?

Comment: Nothing happens, "`X345ga`"  is also a string

Comment: because there are another value that i want to input to the database other than _passwordField1, when i change the code in this, i forgot to change 2 to 1.. Anyway, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

That is because of your line `int _password = Integer.parseInt(_passwordField1);`. You try to pass a String which is not an `Integer` and parse it to int.

Comment: yeah, when i run the program, i enter the string value in the JPasswordField, the error appears. But, what happen if i enter the number value and string value into JPasswordField? what is the best solution to fix this problem sir?

Comment: @Kaoru, pass your password as a `String` and use it like that, don't convert it to `int`. Strings may contain numbers.